# ANOVA Type III Error Message that disregards when I set "type = III"

Tags: r, anova

I am trying to compute an Anova Type III, and I am running into some problems. I am not sure if it a data problem or script error.

First, I ran into a problem where my vif() was giving me an error:

Error in vif.default(model) : there are aliased coefficients in the model.

So, I changed all categorical data into numerics, and I ran the code: vif(model2, type = 'predictor'), and it didn't give me an error, nor did cor().

Then I ran the ANOVA type III:
aov(Measurement ~ Taxon_ID*Date, data=MyData, type = "III")

and it gave me this warning message: Warning: In lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : extra argument ‘type’ will be disregarded

From my understanding, it just ran normal ANOVA and not type III. Common problems are NAs, but I double-checked and I do not have any missing data. Any help or suggestions would be great, thank you!

Comment: Could we please have a [mcve]?

Comment: Neither `stats::aov` nor `stats::lm` have a `type` argument, which would explain the warning.  `car::vif` does, but seems only to accept `"terms"` and `"predictor"` as values.  "Aliased coefficients" tends to suggest that you have an overparameterised model.  Note that changing "all categorical data into numerics" fundamentally changes the model you are fitting.  As @BenBolker says, we really need a minimal reproducible example to help further.

Answer (score 2):

The help for `aov()` (`?aov`) doesn't list a `type` argument.  Maybe you wanted

```r
m1 <- lm(Measurement ~ Taxon_ID*Date, data=MyData)
car::Anova(m1, type = "III")
```

? (It's not clear to me whether type-3 anova makes sense in this case or not, but that's up to you to worry about ...)

We could probably give you more useful advice with a *reproducible example*, but I suspect that would also make the problem transmute into something more suitable for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) — in other words, I think your real problem may have more to do with statistics than with programming.

Comment: ID<- c(rep("A", times = 25), rep("B", times = 25), rep("C", times = 25), rep("D", times = 22))
Month<- c(rep("July", times = 5), rep("Aug", times = 20), rep("Sept", times = 15), rep("Aug", times = 10), rep("Aug", times = 25), rep("Sept", times = 4), rep("Aug", times = 9), rep("June", times = 4), rep("July", times = 5))
Measurements <- c(rnorm(n=25, mean = 8), rnorm(n=25, mean = 6), rnorm(n=25, mean = 7.5), rnorm(n=22, mean = 4))
new_dataframe <- data.frame(cbind(ID, Month, Measurements))
but because vif and cor say that my assumptions are violated, I thought typeIII would solve that